# How can I correctly encrypt the input when there is a space?

Tags: c++, encryption, vigenere

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
//#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

string k;
int key[1024];
int size = 0;
int count = 0;
char text[1024];
char o;

void encrypt(char input[]);
void decrypt(char input[]);

// get arguments from command line 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 if(argc >= 3)
    {
      k = argv[2];
      // removing spaces from key 
      // storing key into char array
      for(int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++)
    {
      if(k.at(i) == ' ')
        {
          key[i] = k.at(i+1);
              i++;
        }
      else
        {
          key[i] = k.at(i);
          // cout << key[i] << endl;
        }

      size++;

    }
      if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0)
    {
      // get text from user
      // encrypt
      cout << "encryption " << endl;
      cin.getline(text, sizeof(text));
      encrypt(text);
    }
      else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
      {
        // get text from user
        // decrypt
        cout << "decryption " << endl;
        decrypt(text);
      }

    }

}

void encrypt(char input[])
{
  string word = input;
  char wkey[word.length()];
  // cout << word.length();
  for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); count++, i++)
    {
      // if input is larger than the key
      // chars of key will repeat until the size is the length of the input
      if(i > size - 1)
        {
          if(i == size)
        {
          count = 0;
        }
          wkey[i] = wkey[count];
        }
      else
        {
          wkey[i] = key[i];
        }



       // if input is a space, cout a space
      if(input[i] == ' ')
    {      
      cout << " ";

    }
      // if input is something other than a letter, then just print it out
      else if(input[i] < 65 || input[i] > 122 || input[i] > 90 && input[i] < 97)
    {
      cout << input[i];
    }
      else
    {
      // ignoring case of the letters in the key
      // give the letters a range of 0-25
      if(wkey[i] >= 65 && wkey[i] <= 90)
        {
          wkey[i]-= 'A';
        }
      else if(wkey[i] >= 97 && wkey[i] <= 122)
        {
          wkey[i]-= 'a';
        }
      //      cout << wkey[i] << endl;

      // if input is uppercase, put it in the range of 0-25
      // make shift by adding to char in key
      // mod by 26 to wrap around
      // o is the encrypted character that will be printed
      if(input[i] >= 65 && input[i] <= 90)
        {
          o = ((wkey[i] + (input[i] - 'A')) % 26) + 'A';
        }
      else if(input[i] >= 97 && input[i] <= 122)
        {
          o = ((wkey[i] + (input[i] - 'a')) % 26) + 'a';
        }
    }
       cout << o;

    } 
}
```

The problem is that I am having trouble encrypting plaintext if that text contains a space. If the text is just one single word, then the program works. In the encryption function where I test the input for a space, I just print out a space, and then the next iteration of the for loop occurs. I think that this problem is occurring because once that next iteration occurs, the character in the key that is at the same index as the space in the input is skipped. I've tried doing an if statement to roll back to the skipped letter in the key, but I still get the wrong output. If anyone could give me some advice on how to fix this problem, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does quoting your input like `"a key with lots of spaces"` help?

Comment: No, because that will then add new characters to my input, which then I will just need to discount, and that would leave me with the same problem with adding a space in the input. Thanks, though.

Comment: @user138002 Could you please explain in more details what do you expect to happen when space occurs? Currently it's going to be skipped obviously because after `if(input[i] == ' ')` you have `else` statement which means everything below this `else` is going to be skipped (except the last line `cout << o;`).

Comment: When there's a space in the input, I expect the output, which is the encrypted text, to have a space in that same location. So if I input the text, "Hello world", I should expect the resulting encrypted text to be something like, "altdw oapvh" depending on what the key is, of course. Instead, my program outputs the correct encryption for the first word, but for the word after the space, it is incorrect.

Comment: Could it be that you are just thrown off by the fact that even for the space, one character of your key is consumed?

Comment: That might be it. So where I cout a space, a character in the key is technically being compared, but it's not being compared with any of the actual letter characters in the input.